# Download button in listview

Tags: android

I have created a custom Listview where i want to add download button. When user click on download button then downloaded that file but how i can do that. I have created a download button but i don't known how i can code for that button.
code

```
public class ListAdptot extends ArrayAdapter<pdf> {
List<pdf> pdffile;
String m_Text;
//activity context
Context context;

//the layout resource file for the list items
int resource;

//constructor initializing the values
public ListAdptot(Context context, int resource, List<pdf> pdfList) {
    super(context, resource, pdfList);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.heroList = pdfList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null, false);
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"DroidSans-Bold.ttf");
    TextView textViewName = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageButton download=view.findViewById(R.id.download);
    textViewName.setTypeface(custom_font);
    pdf PDF= pdffile.get(position);


    textViewName.setText(pdf.getName());
    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
      //What i can do here.
        }
    });
    return view;

}
}
```

Comment: Clear Your Question.

Comment: so basically, you want to know how to download a pdf?

Comment: i known how to download pdf file but i don't known how i can use that code inside the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an interface call it OnItemClickListener
2. Declare a method void onItemClick(int position) inside the interface
3. Create a member variable of OnItemClickListener interface and call it mOnItemClickListener.
4. Add a new parameter to adapter constructor of type OnItemClickListener and call it listener.
5. Initialize mItemClickListener by passed parameter listener.
6. For your button (download button in this case) inside the onClick method call mItemClickListener.onItemClick and pass the position as parameter.

here code:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<pdf> {

//... your code

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<pdf> pdfList, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    super(context, resource, pdfList);

    //... your code

    mOnItemClickListener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    //... you code

    ImageButton download = view.findViewById(R.id.download);
    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
        }
    });

    return view;

}

}
```

In your Activity make this changes:

1. Implement ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener
2. Override onItemClick method
3. Pass "this" as last parameter of ListAdapter
4. Make you List as member variable in activity and call it mPDF (This could be different based on your scenario)
5. Inside the onItemClick you can write your code for download or ... and to know which item was clicked you can use position parameter. for example mPDF.get(position) will return the clicked pdf.

Here Code example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

List<pdf> mPDF;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.what_ever, mPDF, this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {

    pdf clicked = mPDF.get(position);

    // now you can write your download code

}
}
```

Enjoy it.